# Restore Windows Server Service Bus Database from Server to my Local Machine

Tags: windows, azure

I'm in trouble with Azure Service Bus - On Premise. I have an Application that process my On Premise Service Bus Queue, and I need to test an update at that Application, to ensure, we don't lost any items in our queue.

My problem specifically is, how to restore a Microsoft Service Bus 1.1 On Premise, Database to my developing machine to test my update in the processor application.

I try all options in this documentation: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441405.aspx**, but always receiving the follow error:

```
Restore-SBFarm : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ Restore-SBFarm -RunAsAccount "domain\user"
-GatewayDBConnectionStrin ...
+ > ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Data Source=hos...Processing=True
:String) [Restore-SBFarm], SqlException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToDeploySchemaToDatabase,Microsoft.Service
Bus.Commands.RestoreSBFarm
```

**I checked my connection string and all are correct.**

Any help?